# Spring Security is not allowing POST methods

Tags: spring-security

I started using Spring Security on a personal project and I wanted to expose only one path publicly. To do so, I did like that

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    //Enabling access to my public End Points (No authentication needed)
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll();

}
```

The things is, now all my POST requests return *Forbbiden* while the GETS are free to access.

Do you guys happen to have some clue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely because you didn't provide a CSRF token. `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` by default enables CSRF protection for all POST requests.

You can take a look at [`CsrfConfigurer`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/CsrfConfigurer.java) to see how you can modify its behavior, and [`CsrfFilter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/csrf/CsrfFilter.java) to see it in action. The default matcher (`DefaultRequiresCsrfMatcher`) is defined in `CsrfFilter` as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().csrf().disable();
```

The above code did the trick for me, thanks for the help, guys